# default statement is always executed if the last `when` statement is false in `foreach-when` statements

Tags: perl

In my program I am passing a list of `file names` from command-line to my program, and checking whether each file is - `executable`, `readable` and `writable`..

I am using `foreach-when` statement for the above problem.. But there seems to be some problem in the use of `when` and `default` statements, which may be I'm not using correctly, but its giving me unexpected result..

Here's my code: -

```
#!/perl/bin
use v5.14;
use warnings;

foreach (@ARGV) {
    say "*************Checking file $_ *******************";
    when (-r $_) { say "File is Readable"; continue; }
    when (-w $_) { say "File is Writable"; continue; }   # This condition is true
    when (-x $_) { say "File is Executable" }   # This condition is false
    default      { say "None of them" }      # Executed
}
```

I have added a `continue`, only to the first two `when` to make perl check for all the conditions regardless of the name of the file..

Also, I haven't added a `continue` to the second last `when`, because I only want my `default` to be executed if none of the `when` is executed..

The problem here is, if the **last `when` condition is false**, it will not enter the block, and then **it goes on to execute the `default`** even though **my first two `when` statements are satisfied.**

I checked the reason of this problem by changing the order of my `when`, and saw that if only the last `when` is executed, it will see that there is no `continue`, and hence it will not execute the `default` statement..

So, in the above code, I have swapped `-x` and `-r`.. My file is readable, so last `when` in this case will be executed.. And then my `default` statement is not executed..

```
#!/perl/bin
use v5.14;
use warnings;

foreach (@ARGV) {
    say "*************Checking file $_ *******************";
    when (-x $_) { say "File is Executable"; continue; }
    when (-w $_) { say "File is Writable"; continue; }
    when (-r $_) { say "File is Readable" }   # This condition is true
    default      { say "None of them" }   # Not executed
}
```

So, I want to ask, how to handle these kinds of situation.. I want it to work like the way for which `given-when` statement was added to Perl.. 
It should check all the `when`, and skip the `default` if at least one `when` is executed..

Comment: why did u choose 'when' over a simple 'if' statements in this case?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010.. Because I'm reading a book and it's in the exercise of the chapter on `given-when`.. I'm learning Perl, so I want to learn different ways to do a problem.. Of course this can be done with a set of if's..

Comment: I think, havent use given-when construct for a while now, that continue will work as you expect when applied in a given construct and not only with 'when', just a guess

Comment: @soulSurfer2010.. No with `given-when` also, it's the same problem..

Comment: @TLP. I replaced `foreach` with `given(filename)`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `default` isn't an "else condition" but can be seen as a *when that always matches*, it's not really a good match for what you're trying to do. In your default condition, you don't know anything about earlier matches in that block, and you can't break out of the topicalizer earlier without knowing if any later `when` will match, so either you have to "hack it" with a boolean that says one of the earlier matched, or just exchange it for a when that takes care of the "left over" condition;

```
foreach (@ARGV) {
    say "*************Checking file $_ *******************";
    when (-r $_)             { say "File is Readable";   continue; }
    when (-w $_)             { say "File is Writable";   continue; }
    when (-x $_)             { say "File is Executable"; continue; }
    when (!-r && !-w && !-x) { say "None of them" }      
}
```

Comment: Then why was it added to Perl at first place.. It seems that there is a problem with `default`.. I know it's not that strong a matter.. but still as far as a language is concerned, this is an `issue`..

Comment: @RohitJain I agree, it's not one of perl's features that actually makes sense to me either. If you don't want to match several `when` clauses and you don't use `continue` it works as expected, but with the multi match it's not what I would call expected behaviour.

Comment: @Joachim.. Exactly.. And given that `given-when` was mainly added to support `multi-match`.. This seems odd, that we can't actually implement them correctly..

Comment: This answer is wrong. `default` is not a "when that always matches". Each `when` and `default` matches only one time. The `continue` keyword is used to emulate the C-style fall-through of subsequent blocks.

Comment: @TLP Had to look a reference up; [the perlsyn documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html): `default behaves exactly like when(1 == 1) , which is to say that it always matches.`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That is not true. Try it out: `perl -Mv5.12 -we 'for (1,2,3) { when (2) { print } default { print 0 } }'` yields `020`, not `0200`. That seems to be an error in the documentation. It conflicts with the examples given in perlsyn, too.

Comment: @TLP Exactly like `perl -Mv5.12 -we 'for (1,2,3) { when (2) { print } when(1 == 1) { print 0 } }'` It matches everything, but it can be skipped just like every other `when`. I didn't say `default` always runs, just that it always matches if it's not skipped, just like a `when( 1 == 1)`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Ah, I see what you mean. However, in that case, I think you phrased your answer somewhat vague. It *is* an "else" statement, in the sense that it matches when nothing else does. I guess the most lucid way the documentation describes it is that every `when` block has an implicit `break` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that perl does not cache stat results by filename, so you are going to be stating the same file over and over.  It does provide a "_" cache of the last stat issued, so you can:

```
stat $file;
if ( -r _ ) { ... }
if ( -w _ ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

A switch statement is best used for "one of these will match".  Using it for a situation where multiple cases may match is leading to having to abuse the logical structure to make it work.  Having to use fall throughs, and having your cases be order dependent, is a red flag.

A better choice might be to create an array of matches.

```
for my $file (@files) {
    my @flags;
    push @flags, "readable"   if -r $file;
    push @flags, "writable"   if -w $file;
    push @flags, "executable" if -x $file;

    if( @flags ) {
        printf "%s is %s\n", $file, join(", ", @flags);
    }
    else {
        say "$file has no flags set";
    }
}
```

Building an array has the nice side effect of being more flexible.  You can print out one line or several.  It also avoids having to repeat all the flags again at the end, which violates the [DRY Principle](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

An alternative would be to use a do block to set a flag.

```
for my $file (@files) {
    my $has_flags;
    do { say "$file is readable";   $has_flags = 1; } if -r $file;
    do { say "$file is writable";   $has_flags = 1; } if -w $file;
    do { say "$file is executable"; $has_flags = 1; } if -x $file;

    if( !$has_flags ) {
        say "$file has no flags set";
    }
}
```

I mention this mostly to highlight the superiority of building an array of matches.  Using a flag has the disadvantage that each condition must take immediate action making it less flexible.  You must repeatedly set a flag, violating DRY and which can easily be forgotten, whereas with the array the data and flag are the same thing.